# Insert into table from another table after sorting data of first table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am doing something like this in SP,
`insert into @FilteredTbl select * from @MasterTbl`

but now problem is that I want data of `@MasterTbl` sorted before adding into `@FilteredTbl`,

How can I do that ?

---

I found this question and the answer was this :

```
INSERT INTO @FilteredTbl 
SELECT * 
FROM @MasterTbl AS tbl
ORDER BY tbl.OrderbyColumn
```

but this code didn't work , Any kind of help is appreciated

this is the code for the test :

```
declare @table1 table 
(
    a1 int , 
    b1 varchar(20)
) 

insert into @table1 values 
(1,'maza') , (2,'sari') , (3,'ahvaz') , (4,'rasht')

declare @table2 table 
(
    a2 int ,
    b2 varchar(20)
) 

insert into @table2 
select * 
from @table1 t1 
order by t1.b1

select * 
from @table2
```

I am supposed to see the column b2 be sorted , but it is not

Comment: tables in a relational database are unsorted by nature, so unless you have an identity column in your `@FilteredTbl` the `ORDER BY` clause is simply irrelevant and the query optimizer simply ignores it. What's preventing you from using `ORDER BY tbl.OrderbyColumn` when selecting from `@FilteredTbl`?

Comment: Define "did not work"

Comment: @ZoharPeled the query optimizer would not ignore that order by.  I sort by index order a lot to keep fragmentation down.

Comment: @Paparazzi Yeah, that part I wasn't sure of, but the rest of my comment I'm pretty sure is correct.

Comment: this is the code for the test :

Comment: `I am supposed to see the column b2 be sorted` It is not necessary. Unless you have the `ORDER BY` clause in your query

Answer (score 3):

As I've written in my comment - tables in relational databases are unsorted by nature.
This means that your test is incorrect - since your select statement does not have an `order by` clause it's basically returning the rows in an arbitrary order.

A correct test would include an identity column in `@table2` that will record the order of the record inserted into this table:

```
declare @table1 table 
(
    a1 int , 
    b1 varchar(20)
) 

insert into @table1 values 
(1,'maza') , (2,'sari') , (3,'ahvaz') , (4,'rasht')

declare @table2 table 
(
    a2 int ,
    b2 varchar(20),
    c2 int identity(1,1)
) 

insert into @table2 
select * 
from @table1 t1 
order by t1.b1

select * 
from @table2
order by c2
```

Results:

```
a2          b2                   c2
----------- -------------------- -----------
3           ahvaz                1
1           maza                 2
4           rasht                3
2           sari                 4
```

If the order by clause in the `insert into...select` statement was `t1.a1`, the values of `a2` and `c2` would be identical.

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* necessary in T-SQL to add an identity column to your table to sort it. The problem here is that you're inserting the data in a *somewhat* specific order, but not retrieving it in a specific order in the SELECT. I added a single line at the end of your query that would do the trick: ORDER BY B1 (i.e. B1 or some other column). You could also get fancier with functions like ROW_NUMBER to do things like simulate identity columns on the fly, without actually having one on the storage side. Doing an INSERT in the presence of an identity column would indeed mean that you could return the results in the same order as they were inserted - but that wouldn't mean anything if there are duplicates in B1, since the ORDER BY in the INSERT would also be undefined. An identity column helps in the case of poorly specified queries, because without it the table would be treated as a heap and a SELECT without a proper ORDER BY might return results in different, unpredictable orders from one query to the next. If the ORDER BY clause in the retrieval query is specific enough, however, then the identity column becomes irrelevant. For example, if there are dupes in B1 but each combination of B1 and A1 is unique, then a clause like ORDER BY B1, A1 is specific enough to guarantee a well-defined order, one that doesn't change unpredictably from one query to the next. It's a moot point in the case of the 4 values you've provided, however, since all of them are unique for both B1 and A1; ORDER BY B1 should get the job done here. I hope that helps.

```
declare @table1 table 
(
    a1 int , 
    b1 varchar(20)
) 

insert into @table1 values 
(1,'maza') , (2,'sari') , (3,'ahvaz') , (4,'rasht')

declare @table2 table 
(
    a2 int ,
    b2 varchar(20)
) 

insert into @table2 
select * 
from @table1 t1 
order by t1.b1

select * 
from @table2
ORDER BY B1
```

Comment: Of course it's not necessary to add an identity column for sorting, the point of the identity column in my answer is only to show the order the records was inserted into the table. When you execute the last select statement you see the records sorted by `B1`, but that doesn't mean that the rows was inserted to `@table2` in the same order.  It will show the same order of records even if the `insert into...select` was sotred by `a1`.

Comment: Good point Zohar. I think it depends upon a really fine point: does the O.P. need to see the records in the order they were inserted into the table, or by the same ORDER BY criteria as in the INSERT? The specific scenario you mentioned is probably the only one where there's a difference - but it's not usually one of practical use, since the user can always specify an ORDER BY in a SELECT to get the behavior they want. Of course T-SQL is used for all kinds of scenarios though, so I'm sure at some point someone will need to order in the way you described, relying solely on the identity.

Comment: I agree. It's a rare scenario where the order of the records inserted to a table is meaningful. In these rare cases I find using an identity column or inserting the value of row_number() window function as a column to the target table usually enough.

Comment: Yep. I just figured I'd point out the distinction - after recalling that when i was T-SQL rookie, I was sometimes confused about this particular issue. Other readers in same position might think an identity etc. is required by the database engine to execute ordinary ORDER BY clauses in SELECTs. Between our two answers they can see the subtle difference between the two approaches, I think. :)

Comment: @SQLServerSteve As I stated in a comment it is relevant to reduce fragmentation of indexes.  I do it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

A select has NO guaranteed order if there is no sort?

select * from @table2 has NO sort

If you want THAT select sorted then simple

```
select * from @table2 order by b2
```

The order you put them in does NOT effect the order they come out